# Neural Network not recognizing basic input pattern

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I've built a recurrent neural network to predict time series data. I seemed to be getting reasonable results, it would start at 33% accuracy for three classes as expected and would get better up to a point, also as expected. I wanted to test the network just to make sure it's actually working so I created a basic input / output as follows:

```py
in1  in2  in3   out
 1    2    3     0
 5    6    7     1
 9    10   11    2
 1    2    3     0
 5    6    7     1
 9    10   11    2
```

I copied this pattern through a million lines in a csv. I would have assumed the neural network could easily identify this pattern, as it's always the same. I've tried a leaning rate of .1, .01, .001, .0001, but it always stays at about 33% (34% for the .0001 lr). I'll post my code below, should the neural net easily be able to identify this, is there something very wrong with my set up?

```py
import os
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing
from collections import deque
import random
import numpy as np
import time
import random
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM, CuDNNLSTM, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

df = pd.DataFrame()
df = pd.read_csv('/home/drew/Desktop/numbers.csv')

times = sorted(df.index.values)
last_5pct = times[-int(0.1*len(times))]
validation_df = df[(df.index >= last_5pct)]
main_df = df[(df.index < last_5pct)]

epochs = 10
batch_size = 64

train_x = main_df[['in1','in2','in3']]
validation_x = validation_df[['in1','in2','in3']]
train_y = main_df[['out']]
validation_y = validation_df[['out']]

train_x = train_x.values
validation_x = validation_x.values
train_x = train_x.reshape(train_x.shape[0],1,3)
validation_x = validation_x.reshape(validation_x.shape[0],1,3)

model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(train_x.shape[1:]), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(train_x.shape[1:]), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Dense(32, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(3, activation="softmax"))

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001, decay=1e-6)

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
             optimizer=opt,
             metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_x, train_y,
          batch_size=batch_size, 
          epochs=epochs,
          validation_data=(validation_x, validation_y))
```

result:

```py
Train on 943718 samples, validate on 104857 samples
Epoch 1/10
943718/943718 [===] - 125s 132us/sample - loss: 0.0040 - acc: 0.3436 - val_loss: 2.3842e-07 - val_acc: 0.3439
Epoch 2/10
943718/943718 [===] - 111s 118us/sample - loss: 2.1557e-06 - acc: 0.3437 - val_loss: 2.3842e-07 - val_acc: 0.3435
...
Train on 943718 samples, validate on 104857 samples
Epoch 1/10
943718/943718 [==============================] - 125s 132us/sample - loss: 0.0040 - acc: 0.3436 - val_loss: 2.3842e-07 - val_acc: 0.3439
Epoch 2/10
943718/943718 [==============================] - 111s 118us/sample - loss: 2.1557e-06 - acc: 0.3437 - val_loss: 2.3842e-07 - val_acc: 0.3435
Epoch 6/10
719104/943718 [=====================>........] - ETA: 25s - loss: 2.4936e-07 - acc: 0.3436
```

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `pytorch` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Try using `'sparse_categorical_accuracy'` for your metric instead and see if that changes anything. The regular `'accuracy'` metric *may* be expecting a one-hot encoded target, but I'm not sure.

Comment: same results with 'sparse_categorical_accuracy'

Comment: I wonder about the accuracy same as you, but your validation loss is zero. I'm running code based on yours, and the output of `model.predict(validation_x[:6])` looks good.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not predicting time series result, so there is no need to return sequence after the second `LSTM` layer.

If you change the second `LSTM` to:

```
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(train_x.shape[1:])))
```

Then, you should get high accuracy.